# call parent javascript function from iframe

Tags: node-webkit

In node-webkit, call from  iframe javascript to parent javascript doesnt work for me.

I am trying to launch a link in the iframe on the default browser as a result
I want to call a function in the parent window so as to call:

```
gui.Shell.openExternal("link");
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to open?

Comment: I am trying to open a link to another server running elsewhere.It would be sufficient if I can get google.com to open in the default browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do, is to intercept links in the internal frame.

Here we have an iframe where all links will open in the default browser, not in the Node WebKit context.  I hope this helps.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.gui = require('nw.gui');

    handleLinks = function(event)
    {
            var href;

            function checkLinks(element) 
            {
                if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') 
                {
                    href = element.getAttribute('href');
                    if (href)
                    {
                        gui.Shell.openExternal(href);
                        // important, prevent the default event from happening!
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }   
                }                   
                else if (element.parentElement) 
                {
                  checkLinks(element.parentElement);
                }
            }
            checkLinks(event.target);
    };

     function isLoaded() 
     {
       // let's see if the iframe has finished loading
       var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');

       if (iframe && iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document &&
           iframe.contentWindow.document.body &&
           iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML) 
           {
            //now deal with links
            iframe.contentWindow.document.body.addEventListener('click', handleLinks, false);
           } 
           else 
           {
             // not yet, let's wait a bit and try again
             setTimeout(isLoaded, 300);
           }
     };
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.google.com" onLoad="isLoaded();" style="width: 100%;" seamless="true" nwdisable nwfaketop></iframe>
   <div>
    Links in the normal browser should still work in the Node Webkit environment.
   </div>
   <footer>
    <a href="http://www.yoursitehere.com">Whaddayaknow</a>
   </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pleasure - Node Webkit is such a powerful tool!

Comment: This doesn't work if you're loading a external website in the iframe, right? You get the error: `SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a frame with origin "http://...". Protocols, domains, and ports must match`

Comment: I actually used it to load an external website, but in a Node Webkit application. I never ran into this security issue though. Can you post a sample that recreates this issue?

Comment: I'm using your code: `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.addEventListener`. This generate the error.

Comment: I don't get any error with the sites I'm using, using the exact same code.