# Node-webkit: using the same codebase for web- and desktop application

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, node-webkit

I was given the following to consider:

- Develop desktop application using Nodeweb kit.
- Also develop web application using the same code base.
- Applications should look identical.
- Both apps must use the same code base. The reason for this is to cut down development expenses.

If it was up to me I would not even consider using node-webkit for desktop. There are far better desktop solutions for Win platforms. For web application using Node is certanly viable.

But people who plan the project somehow think Node is a way to go for both apps.

After lots of thinking, I came to the conclusion that doing what they want will only increase dev and maintenance costs.

I consider using express (maybe even Sails.js) for web application. I made some tests where I used express on node-webkit and it run just fine.

Certanly NW is powerfull platform (popcorn). Just in my case I fail to see how can it cut down the  dev expense

Am I right to be against this solution? Is this a plausible decision and I am not seeing another solution?

### Any opinion is very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually done exactly this, and it worked very well. The trick was to write some Node Webkit code that will "detect" that it's running as a desktop application, instead of a web app, and thus integrate with desktop notifications etc.

Yes, it was more work than just writing a web app, but it was also less work (and maintenance) than developing separate applications. You get to use a lot of common code, because of the fact that you are running in a browser already, that I feel the project saved a lot of time.

In fact, I am currently working on another application that requires some desktop features (file access, notifications) but the same functionality as the web application, and I'm proposing that the development happens in Node Webkit.

The important criteria here for me is that both applications are 90% the same, the desktop just adds things you don't normally have on the web. So the core of the application is exactly the same AngularJS application, with some JavaScript injected by the Node Webkit startup page to add the required desktop behaviour.

Comment: Where did you start first? As a Desktop version?

Comment: I started with the web application first, once that was working, I wrapped it inside an inner frame and used that to control the web application. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627591/call-parent-javascript-function-from-iframe/19842882#19842882 to see how I managed to do that.

Comment: I believe, our requirement is to start Desktop first.

Comment: Nothing stops you from going desktop first, just make sure you plan it properly and don't code "desktop" features into the core app, but rather inject them at runtime. Then you are building both at once - and look like the hero :P

Answer (score 0):

You haven't presented reasons why you think node-webkit is not a suitable option for desktop application.

On the other hand I think client's opinion that development in node and node-webkit will be able to cut down costs is not ungrounded.

nw.js (formerly node-webkit) is basically a Chromium browser with intergrated node.js engine. So if you develop a web-application using node.js (and any of its frameworks) then you will be able to reuse it in nw.js fairly easy.

Comment: I have no reasons agaunst nodewebkit, very good platform. My concern is developing two applications, that in theoretically should work the same... steucturing them properly so using the same code can be made possible. And still, two apps are still different. I wonder has anyone ever done this? Any advice how to make start steps?

Comment: If you described the nature of applications a bit, I could be more specific.

Comment: Desktop app will be using sqllote, which will be encrypted. App is typical CRUD with some calculations. Lots of forms and many tables. Same goes for web version, just that web version will use sqlserver instead.

Comment: Well, why would they be radically different if the only difference is db back-end?

Comment: Basic crud and forms are same. Also calculations. There is a whole list of different features for desktop and web version. Small things, but many of them. I am concerned how to branch the  code. I am afraid of if/else hell.

Comment: " I am afraid of if/else hell." maybe use object and template inheritance then?

Comment: Templates and business logic will be the same. I am thinking of the code that is not the same. There is always something which is different. Would you be kind to provide me with short generic example regarding object and template inheritance? :)

Comment: For example. I have web app using Express.js and lets say Jade as templating engine. Now I make NW and copy all of the code inside, and make it run. NW version will have more features, such as  more calculations offered and smiliar things. My concern is how to keep as much code as possible from web version, and yet be easily able to add specific features. I am aware it is not possible to keep them identical, since they are different platforms to begin with. But how to save as much code as possible. What would be ideal application skeleton?

Comment: I would create webapp first and then would use Jade's inheritance features: http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/ to extend templates for nw version. Probably business logic could be mostly same for both projects; desktop part of it would just not be used in web.

Comment: Is it advisable to use some MVC framework for web version and simply copy the code in NW (with small changes to make it run)??