# How to access the contents of an iframe in nw.js?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, nw.js

I need to capture the contents of an iframe in **nw.js**. The page is located on a different domain. I tried to access it normally (`myIframe.document`), but I get an empty html document (probably some form of cross domain security or other). I can however access the contents of the iframe from console and I'm guessing there is some setting I'm missing that will allow me to do the same directly from my code. I don't need however the iframe to be able to access **nw.js** (for security reasons it'll be even better if it's impossible).

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="800" height="600" id="myIframe"></iframe>
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        // Making sure it's actually loaded with help of jquery
        $('#myIframe').ready(function () {
            console.log(window.frames[0].document);
            // Returns:
            // <html>
            // <head></head>
            // <body></body>
            // </html>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll find some help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627591/call-parent-javascript-function-from-iframe/19842882#19842882 - it's about accessing the iframe and manipulating it. With a bit of a tweak, I believe it will work for you.

Comment: @Ewald I had a look in your code and it turns out the problem was my use of jquery. The iframe isn't really ready when the jquery's `ready` callback is called, however it is ready when `onload` event is triggered.

Comment: That's excellent, I'm glad you found the problem, best wishes with your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out I can access the contents of the iframe just like that in **nw.js** and I was just doing something wrong in my original code.

The problem was the use of jquery `ready`. When I tried to access the iframe when `ready` was triggered, I got an empty document, but when I did the same from iframe's `onload` callback, I actually got all the contents.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="800" height="600" id="myIframe" onload="loaded()"></iframe>
<script>
    function loaded()
    {
        console.log(window.frames[0].document);
        // Returns the actual page
    }
</script>
```

---

**P.S.** It is advised to use `nwdisable` and `nwfaketop` attributes when loading unsafe content (such as external site) into an `iframe` in **nw.js**.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="800" height="600" nwdisable nwfaketop></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the whole document of a URL you can use this method after it loads:

```
var Content=(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(iframeID.contentDocument);
```